# In XML DTDs is it possible to provide multiple definitions for same element depending on whether it will be document root or not?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, dtd

For example, lets say one XML file `book_list.xml` is a list view of books with 0 or more books each having only 3 child elements id, title and author.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookList SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<bookList>
    <book>
        <id>123</id>
        <title>One Book Title</title>
        <author>......</author>
    </book>

    <book>
        <id>456</id>
        <title>Another Book Title</title>
        <author>......</author>
    </book>
</bookList>
```

Another XML file `book.xml` is a detailed view of a single book with many other required attributes such as publisher, year, isbn. The root element for this document is `book`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<book>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>One Book Title</title>
    <author>.....</author>
    <isbn>......</isbn>
    <year>......</year>
    <publisher>......</publisher>
</book>
```

My question is can we provide overloaded definitions for `book` element in a single DTD where `book` element has only 3 child elements when it is a child of `bookList` but is "required" to have many other child elements if `book` itself is the document root or do we have to create separate DTD files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest you can come to this type of functionality with DTD is by using [`INCLUDE` and `IGNORE` sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-condition-sect).

You can create parameter entities to hold the INCLUDE/IGNORE values. The DTD can be setup to default to one of the `book` declarations.

To switch to the other `book` declaration, you need to redefine your parameter entities in the internal subset of your DOCTYPE declaration.

**Example** (validated in oXygen using Xerces)

**books.dtd**

```
<!ENTITY % bigbook   "IGNORE">
<!ENTITY % smallbook "INCLUDE">

<!ELEMENT bookList (book)+>

<![%smallbook;[
<!ELEMENT book (id,title,author)>
]]>

<![%bigbook;[
<!ELEMENT book (id,title,author,isbn,year,publisher)>
]]>

<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
```

**book_list.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE bookList SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<bookList>
    <book>
        <id>123</id>
        <title>One Book Title</title>
        <author>......</author>
    </book>    
    <book>
        <id>456</id>
        <title>Another Book Title</title>
        <author>......</author>
    </book>
</bookList>
```

**book.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "books.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % bigbook   "INCLUDE">
<!ENTITY % smallbook "IGNORE">
]>
<book>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>One Book Title</title>
    <author>.....</author>
    <isbn>......</isbn>
    <year>......</year>
    <publisher>......</publisher>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

When an element is defined in DTDs, its definition will be the same, whatever the context you are using this element, and the only possibility would be to provide an overall definition of your `book` element with optional tags or attributes.

However it is a feature you have (with a few conditions) in XML Schemas, where you can provide local definitions for element content.